# How do I assign variables for makefile

Tags: makefile

I'm experimenting with using variables with makefile and can't seem to use them consistently.

The following code (in file silly2.mak):

```
SUBS = src
SSUBS=/src2
SHELL=/bin/sh

silly5:
    echo '<<<' $$SUBS '--' $$SSUBS '--' $$SHELL '>>>'
```

When run with:

```
me@ubuntu:/usr/local/hsfsys$ make -f silly2.mak silly5
```

Gives the following output:

```
echo '<<<' $SUBS '--' $SSUBS '--' $SHELL '>>>'
<<< -- -- /bin/bash >>>
```

Why does 'SHELL' seem to work better than my other variables? Is it some sort of reserved word? I've tried moving the order of the variables around and looking at online documentation, but still don't understand why echo picks up the value of SHELL, but not SUBS or SSUBS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this

```
SUBS = src
SSUBS=/src2
SHELL=/bin/sh

all:
    echo '<<<' $(SUBS) '--' $(SSUBS) '--' $(SHELL) '>>>'
```

Comment: Thanks, this worked. It seems odd that SHELL should be more robust in terms of being read, bit I guess, when in doubt, I'll just use the parentheses as a safety device

Comment: @user1245262, I think you're still misunderstanding.  `make` *always* requires the parentheses for variable expansion.  The reason `$$SHELL` appeared to work is that `SHELL` is defined in the shell, and you escaped the `$` so all of the variables got passed into the shell so *it* would expand them.  Since `SUBS` and `SSUBS` don't exist in the shell, that doesn't work.

Comment: @CarlNorum - Thanks. Now the differences make sense.